# KDiff3: "There is a line end style conflict"

Tags: kdiff3

I am trying to use KDiff3 to solve conflicts on windows. But when run the merge I get:

KDiff3: "There is a line end style conflict"

And nothing is merged/solved:

[image: first screenshot]

Even though I selected DOS line ending before running the merge:

[image: second screenshot]

Any ideas?

It seems to work if I just save instead of pressing the Merge button. That could be a solution.

Comment: Why don't you accept the solution ?

Comment: What you choose is about the result of Merge. Since a conflict occurs during Merge operation, first choosing a line ending and then running Merge practically resets your choice back to conflict. Run Merge, get a conflict, make your choice, and then save.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Here's a screenshot to walk you through the process that Matt Wilkie described in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28912211/4298200).

1. Click in the C pane.
2. Choose an encoding other than 'conflict'
3. Save

[image]

Comment: I found no need to do step 1. (kdiff3 Version 0.9.98 (64 bit))

Comment: Ant note that in the newer version that feature works better! in 1.9.5 it solves conflict automatically!

Answer (score 52):

What worked for me:

- make the output pane active (click in it),
- manually choose both *Encoding* and *Line end style* drop down choices,
- save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).

Without doing all three steps, I just kept getting the same error popup. Choosing *Use A everwhere* and/or related merge menu items had no effect.